# How to loop windows forms objects incremently

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have some webBrowsers on my C# application, infact I have 10. webBrowser0, webBrowser1, webBrowser2 and so on..

Anyways, I'm performing a loop to count each screen to place a webBrowser on each screen I have, all this is done easily, but in my loop, if have something like this.

```
for (index = 0; index <= totalScreens; index++)
{

if (index == 0)
{
webBrowser0.Width = x;
webBrowser0.Height = x;
}

if (index == 1)
{
webBrowser1.Width = x;
webBrowser1.Height = x;
}

}
```

As you cansee, I'm doubling up on code quite a lot, so if I could refer to webBrowser{index} that would be perfect but that of course isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define an array

```
WebBrowser[] browsers = new WebBrowser[] { webBrowser0, webBrowser1, ... };
```

and use `browsers[index]` in your loop.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your support, I chose this solution as it was small and basic, exactly what my simple application needs.

Answer (score 5):

Create collection of your WebBrowsers.

```
List<WebBrowser> browsers = new List<WebBrowser> {webBrowser0,webBrowser1};

for (index = 0; index <= totalScreens; index++)
{
    if(index < browsers.Count)
    {
        browsers[index].Width = x;
        browsers[index].Height = x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you could do is use

```
var myBrowsers = new List<WebBrowser>().
```

Then you add your WebBrowsers with

```
myBrowsers.Add(new WebBrowser());  // Do this 10 times for 10 browsers.
```

In that way you can use

```
myBrowser[index]
```

or to access each one in a loop

```
foreach (var aBrowser in myBrowsers)
{
   aBrowser...
}
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; i < myBrowsers.Count; i++)
{
  myBrowser[i]...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working recently with the same problem as you lots of controls and a for to locate them all, I've chosen to use a List of controls (or simply use the Property Controls in the form if you have the controls ordered correctly) and then I looped over it setting their location calculating each position each time.

See you.

Comment: I'm not sure if you know already, but you don't have to calculate their positions if you use the Bounds array within the screens. The Framework already knows exactly where it's calculated to start and finish, width and height. My application is just for terminal use within interchages.

Comment: Well that was what I wanted to say with calculate, using the control bounds, we developed custom list controls, were you had a constant heigh, and (0,0) as initial position, so at each iteration you worked with the position of the posterior element of the list and adding the heigh. I hope I could make me understand :)